# WPF: Easiest way to add control to grid based on ListView selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` which contains items that should represent certain settings, which can be changed by the user. I am looking for the easiest way to link the `ListViewItem` to a custom user control.

What I have now:

```
    <ListView 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        SelectionChanged="SettingsListViewSelectionChanged">

        <ListViewItem x:Name="PathSettings" Content="Path"/>
        <ListViewItem x:Name="HideShowTvShows" Content="Hide/Show TV Shows"/>
    </ListView>
```

And then in the code behind I figure out which item was clicked, and attach the corresponding `UserControl` to the `Grid`.

```
    private void SettingsListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = e.Source as ListView;

        if (listView != null)
        {
            SettingsContentPanel.Children.Clear();

            if (listView.SelectedItem.Equals(_pathSettings))
            {
                SettingsContentPanel.Children.Add(_pathSettings);

                _pathSettings.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
                _pathSettings.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            }
            if (listView.SelectedItem.Equals(_hideShowTvShowsSettings))
            {
                SettingsContentPanel.Children.Add(_hideShowTvShowsSettings);

                _hideShowTvShowsSettings.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
                _hideShowTvShowsSettings.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Grid itself:

```
    <Grid 
        x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Is there a way to get rid of the boiler plate code behind and use XAML for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="SettingsContentPanel"
                  Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyLstView}"/>
```

Comment: Trying to understand ContentPresenter, but not much luck so far. If I set the `Content` property of the ContentPresenter then nothing happens. My UserControls are set as `Content` but never actually visualized. Would you happen to have pointers, otherwise I better revert my changes to the boilerplate variant

Comment: @bas edit your question and post your current XAML, and show what behavior you get, and if you get any errors in the Visual Studio output Window, then post that too.

Comment: GOD! The stupidity! I forgot to remove the lines of code where I set the user controls visibility to `Hidden`...... It works. Thx! :)