# WPF SettingsDialog using a ListView's SelectedItem and a ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I thought I cooked up something rather brilliant, but it's not working (yet!).

I am trying to get rid of all code behind in a `SettingsDialog` where a `SettingsGroup` can be selected by the user, which will consequently be visualized to the right of `ListView` (a similar settings dialog as Visual Studio has).

I was [tipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632760/wpf-easiest-way-to-add-control-to-grid-based-on-listview-selection/20633272?noredirect=1#20633272) to use a `ContentPresenter`, which I did, but then later realized that the tipper probably meant to rely on only XAML to get the job done.

This is what I got so far.

Declaring the `SettingsGroup`s in XAML:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <w:DefinePathsUserControl x:Key="DefinePathSettingsGroup"></w:DefinePathsUserControl>
        <w:HideShowTvShowsUserControl x:Key="HideShowTvShowsSettingsGroup"></w:HideShowTvShowsUserControl>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Add the left hand side `SettingsGroup` selector (a simple `ListView`):

```
    <ListView 
        x:Name="SettingsGroupSelector"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0">

        <ListViewItem 
            x:Name="PathSetting" 
            Tag="{StaticResource DefinePathSettings}"  
            Content="Path"/>
        <ListViewItem 
            x:Name="HideShowTvShowsSetting" 
            Tag="{StaticResource HideShowTvShowsSettings}" 
            Content="Hide/Show TV Shows"/>
    </ListView>
```

And then I thought I could simply bind the `ContentPresenter` to the tag of the selected item in the `ListView`, like:

```
    <ContentPresenter 
        x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Content="{Binding Source=SettingsGroupSelector, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
```

Unfortunately for me, this does not show anything in my `ContentPresenter`. I also don't get any errors in my output window.

Who can help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  <ContentPresenter 
    x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Content="{Binding Source=SettingsGroupSelector, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
```

to this

```
  <ContentPresenter 
    x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Content="{Binding ElementName=SettingsGroupSelector, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
```

More information on [specifying the Binding Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)